# dont display div data not provided

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am working with mvc4 and displaying data from my model in to cshtml views.

When setting data in to the markup, I adding it in to div tags.

Is there a way in mvc that if the model property is not set, dont display the div?

Sample of my markup

```
<div class="myclass"> @Model.Text </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test for a value being set like so:

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Text)) 
{
    <div class="myclass"> @Model.Text </div>
}
```

---

**Update:** If you want to incorporate the logic for whether or not to render an element based on its value, you could create a [Custom HTML Helper](http://www.aspnetwiki.com/page%3acreating-custom-html-helpers) method.

Comment: Thanks for this but anyway not to use the if statement - dont want to bloat my code with such. Any html helper or similar available to do this?

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping it in a null check

```
@{
  if (@Model.Text != null)
  {
     <div class="myclass"> @Model.Text </div>
  }
}
```